# Assigning NAs into a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement, dplyr

I have been trying to assign NAs by using for loop, but is not working and I know there are possible easiest ways to do this.

I want to create an extra column (just like the column in the example named Desire_Output) in which I will assign NA to any row that in the Value column has a number higher than 1. Also, I want to assign NAs to the next following two rows. If there are NAs in the Value column, just also put NAs in the desire output column.

Here is the example:

```
Event<- c(1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,7)
Value<- c(5,3,0,0,0,2,0,1,10,0,0,NA,NA,NA,1,0,8,0,0)
Desire_output<- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,0,NA,NA,NA)
A<- data.frame(Event,Value,Desire_output)


   Event Value Desire_output
1      1     5            NA
2      2     3            NA
3      2     0            NA
4      2     0            NA
5      2     0             0
6      2     2            NA
7      2     0            NA
8      3     1            NA
9      3    10            NA
10     4     0            NA
11     4     0            NA
12     4    NA            NA
13     4    NA            NA
14     4    NA            NA
15     5     1             1
16     6     0             0
17     6     8            NA
18     6     0            NA
19     7     0            NA
```

This is what I tried to do, but when I getvto the NAs in the Value column I started to have some troubles.

```
for (f in 1:(nrow(A)-1)){
  if(A$Value2[f] > 1){
    A$Value2[f]<- NA
    A$Value2[f+1]<- NA
    A$Value[f+2]<- NA
     }else{
  }
}
```

Please let me know if you have an easiest way to do it with any other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first copy `Value` column to `Desired_output` column and find out the indices (`inds`) where `Value` is greater than 1 and add `NA` to that row and next two rows as well.

```
A$Desired_output <- A$Value
inds <- which(A$Value > 1)
A$Desired_output[unique(c(inds, inds + 1, inds + 2))] <- NA
A

#   Event Value Desired_output
#1      1     5             NA
#2      2     3             NA
#3      2     0             NA
#4      2     0             NA
#5      2     0              0
#6      2     2             NA
#7      2     0             NA
#8      3     1             NA
#9      3    10             NA
#10     4     0             NA
#11     4     0             NA
#12     4    NA             NA
#13     4    NA             NA
#14     4    NA             NA
#15     5     1              1
#16     6     0              0
#17     6     8             NA
#18     6     0             NA
#19     7     0             NA
```

Comment: Hi Ronak Shah , coming back to this question, how would you modify the code if the last Value is higher than 1? I tried with a dataframe but it's giving me an error, obviously because it is assigning NA to the last row, but also the last row +1, and +2 (which are rows that doesn't exist). How to deal with this problem? I tried a for loop, but wondering if there is an easier way.

Comment: You can do something like this : `newinds <- unique(c(inds, inds + 1, inds + 2))` then keep only those which are less than number of rows. `newinds <- newinds[newinds <= nrow(A)]` and use it to assign values `A$Desired_output[newinds] <- NA`

Comment: Excellent! Thanks Ronak.

Answer (score 1):

I think this gives what you're after, but other solutions may be less laborious.

```
Event<- c(1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,7)
Value<- c(5,3,0,0,0,2,0,1,10,0,0,NA,NA,NA,1,0,8,0,0)

A<- data.frame(Event,Value,Desired_output) 

A["Desired_Output"] <- 0

for(i in seq(length(A$Value))){

  if(!is.na(A$Desired_Output[i])){

    if(A$Value[i] > 1 & !is.na(A$Value[i])){

      A$Desired_Output[c(i, i+1, i+2)] <- NA

    }else if(is.na(A$Value[i])){

      A$Desired_Output[i] <- NA

    }else{

      A$Desired_Output[i] <- A$Value[i]

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: I'm unclear to what you mean in these last two sentences: "Also, I want to assign NAs to the next following two rows. If there are NAs in the Value column, just also put NAs in the desire output column." Could you bullet point what you'd like you code to do, please and I'll see if I can provide a better answer.

Comment: Sure James, in the A dataframe, the column named "Desired output" is how exactly I want the outcome of the code to be. So, first if a number in the Value column is higher than 1 assign it an NA in the "Desire_output" column, and not only for that row, but also assign NAs for the two coming rows (i+1) and (i+2). Like it is shown in the desire output column

Comment: For example in the row # 2, the "Value" column has a number = 3, which means it is higher than 1. Therefore, in the "Desire_Output" column it is assign an NA in that same row. If the number in the Value column is higher than 1, I want also to assign NA to the two following rows. Therefore, for the next two rows (rows 3 and 4) I need to assign NAs (and that's why there are NA in the Desire_output columns 3 and 4.
The same condition is applied to the whole dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I've updated my response. Turns out I don't know how to do it without a loop!

Answer (score 1):

You might use the ifelse. In the below code I have used the OR statement inside the ifelse code.

```
A$Desire_output<- ifelse(A$Value>1 | is.na(A$Value), NA, A$Value)
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's only assigning NAs to the rows which have a value higher than 1, but not the coming two rows after that NA.